# File manager with spring-loaded folders?

Tags: gui, file-copy, file-manager, drag-and-drop

One thing I miss about Finder, Mac OS X's file manager, is the spring-loaded folder function where if you drag a file(s) over another folder long enough, the folder would open and you can "navigate" through folders while holding down the mouse button until you reach where you want to drop the file.

Does such a feature exist in Linux file managers? Is so, which ones? Thanks.

BTW, I prefer lightweight programs with as few dependencies as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The just tested in Nautilus, the default file manager for Gnome support this by default. It feels like about 1500ms for folders to open while hovering over them as a drag target. I'm sure that time is configurable. (Tested with nautilus 2.32.2.1 on PLD-Linux TH)

I also fired up KDE and tested both Konqueror and Dolphin. The default configurations don't seem to support it but it's a little funky because the desktop folder widget DOES support it, so obviously some parts of the system are aware enough to handle the case. I suspect this might turn out to be something you could enable if you knew where the setting was. (Tested with Dolphin 1.6 and Konqueror 4.6 on OpenSUSE)

Comment: @Caled That's good to know. What about Thunar, PCManFM, or any other file manager? I am hoping for something with less dependencies and lighter weight. Thanks! (editing original question to say that)

Comment: pcmanfm 0.9.9 does not support something like that.